# Key click sound like in EDEX ui

Tags: keyboard

I started using [GitSquared/edex-ui](https://github.com/GitSquared/edex-ui) and very liked keyboard sounds. I tried using `bucklespring` but it was too mechanical for me. I googled but I didn't find anything useful.

Do you know how or which tools can make key click sound like in EDEX-ui?